# Prefetch related not working in django admin

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm trying to show name of related model in my django admin and i'm using prefetch related but i still got 200+ sql queries how can i solve that?

models.py

```
class ObjectList(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sections = models.ManyToManyField('SectionList', default=None, related_name='object_sections', blank=True)

 


class CleanSections(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class SectionList(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    object = models.ManyToManyField(ObjectList, related_name='sections_object', default=None)
    clean_sections = models.ForeignKey(CleanSections, to_field='uuid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                       related_name='sections_clean_name')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.clean_sections.name}'
```

admin.py

```
class ObjectListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('uuid', 'name')
    list_filter = ('name',)
    search_fields = ('uuid', 'name')
    ordering = ('uuid', 'name')
    fields = ('uuid', 'name', 'sections')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        base_qs = super(ObjectListAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return base_qs.prefetch_related('sections__clean_sections')
```

Comment: Exactly what is the `__str__` of the `SectionList`?

Comment: oh i didnt add that, ill change my question

Comment: try removing __str__ func and test again